# How to copy an Erlang digraph?

Tags: erlang, elixir, directed-graph

How do I copy an Erlang digraph? There doesn't seem to be a copy function in the docs. Do I have to build a copy manually?

I'm coding in Elixir.

Comment: Why do you want to make a copy of a non mutable variable?

Comment: @Pascal digraphs are mutable in erlang, they use ETS for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense for performance, but it looks very weird and I think there should be a bigger warning in the documentation (take care when you pass the digraph from one process to another... maybe the reason to make a copy :o)

Comment: The graph isn't mutable by any process other than the creator. There are flags to make it unreadable by other processes as well. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I can see to copy an entire digraph is to use the [`digraph_utils:subgraph/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/digraph_utils.html#subgraph-2) with `Vertices = digraph:vertices(Digraph)`.

**Test:**
Creating A->B graph in `Digraph`, copying it to `Digraph2` and checking that it is a different graph by adding `"C"` vertex only to `Digraph2`.

```
1> Digraph = digraph:new().
{digraph,16400,20497,24594,true}
2> digraph:add_vertex(Digraph,"A").
"A"
3> digraph:add_vertex(Digraph,"B").
"B"
4> digraph:add_edge(Digraph,"A","B").
['$e'|0]
5> Digraph2 = digraph_utils:subgraph(Digraph, digraph:vertices(Digraph)). 
{digraph,28691,32788,36885,true}
6> digraph:add_vertex(Digraph2, "C").
"C"
7> digraph:vertices(Digraph).
["B","A"]
8> digraph:vertices(Digraph2).
["C","B","A"]
```